# Pass array of strings as raw data in ruby on rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, http

I want to integrate an API with the following curl

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://example.com:80/replay' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '["aa","bb","cc"]'
```

What I have tried already is-

```
uri = URI('http://example.com:80/replay')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
header = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
new_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
new_request.body = arr.to_json
res = http.request(new_request)
```

Here my arr is ["aa","bb","cc"]
But it's giving me 500 response code. However it works when I import the above curl in Postman.

TIA

Comment: [curl-to-ruby](https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/) can generate net/http code from curl requests. (use `--data` instead of `--data-raw`)

Comment: @Stefan: The OP does not use any `@` character in his command. Shouldn't then be `--data` and `--data-raw` act in the same way? From the man page about the curl command: _--data-raw is almost the same but does not have a special interpretation of the @ character_.

Comment: @user1934428 I was referring to the external `curl-to-ruby` tool which only supports `--data` (it would ignore `--data-raw`)

Comment: `"But it's giving me 500 response code"`. Are you sure your request is even the problem? If just sending the wrong input causes a `500 - Internal Server Error` something on the other end isn't as it should be.